# statsmodels.formula.api ols 'matrices not aligned' error

Tags: python, matrix, statsmodels

I'm trying to compute a simple regression on three variables, score, treatment which is 0-1 categorical and days. All three are columns of df.

```
response_delay = sm.ols(formula='score ~ C(treatment)+days', data=df)
print response_delay.fit().summary()
```

I get a `matrices not aligned` error which I don't understand since there is only one matrix, df.
I tried dropping na values but still same error.

Comment: Could you provide sample data so that we can test it?

Comment: Will need fully reproducible example and/or the full traceback to be able to help.